# How to define default argument value based on previous arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, default-value

I want to define a `resize(h, w)` method, and I want to be able to call it in one of two ways:

1. `resize(x,y)`
2. `resize(x)`

Where, in the second call, I want `y` to be equal to `x`. Can I do this in the method definition or should I do something like `resize(x,y=None)` and check inside:

```
if y is None:
    y = x
```

Comment: yes, your `None` code is the preferred way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I do this in the method definition

No. During the method definition there's no way to know what value `x` might have at run-time. Default arguments are evaluated once at definition time, there's no way to save a dynamic value  for `y`.

> or should I do something like `resize(x,y=None)` and check inside

exactly. This is a common idiom in Python.

Comment: Thx! But cant I give the function an indication to look in other arguments passed, something like _resize(x, y = argv[1])_ in a way that somewhat resembles the main in C?

Comment: @CIsForCookies you could do something like that but it will only be evaluated once when the method is defined. It won't be re-evaluated for every invocation.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Jim's answer, in the case that `None` is valid as a parameter value, you could use variable length arguments feature (positional, and/or keyword). Example of use for positional:

```
def resize(x,*args):
    if args:
        if len(args)>1:
           raise Exception("Too many arguments")
        y = args[0]
    else:
        y = x
```

in that example, you have to pass `x`, but you can pass 0 or more extra positional arguments. Of course you have to do the checking manually, and you lose the `y` keyword.